# Why does list.function in thymeleaf making display error in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

My code is:

```
<p>Reader's books:</p>
<div th:each="book : ${books}" th:unless="${books.empty}" >
    <a th:href="@{/books/{id}(id = ${book.getId_book()})}" th:text="${book.getName()}"></a>
</div>
<div th:if="${books.empty}"><p>Reader has 0 books!</p></div>
```

All is working, but IntelliJ shows errors. How I can fix that?[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmDij.png)

I tried to make auto fix by IntelliJ, but it is not worked. I also tried to use (== null), but I have errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.